# How do I revert a file in TFS

Tags: tfs, version-control

On occasion, I'll end up checking in a file to our TFS db that I didn't intend to.
Reverting to the prior version is quite tedious with my current approach.

If there a fast way to revert a file to a prior version in TFS? I'm open to command line, powertool, or UI approaches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the power tools:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx

1. For VS2013 - [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)
2. For VS2015 - [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)

Comment: I haven't used TFS since just after answering this, but I seem to remember that it was pretty obvious after install. I think it was a right click option.

Comment: You can see a more detailed answer to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7124274/62278

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use the command line, or install the tools, you can also do it in an old-school way:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2009/01/10/how-to-revert-changes-checked-into-tfs-version-control.aspx

Comment: This still works in VS2017, though some menu commands have shuffled around ("Get Specific Version" is now in "Advanced" sub-menu for example). Main difference is TFS may attempt to Auto-Resolve on check in, tossing your reversion. To disable Auto-Resolve before you check in: Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> Uncheck "Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated"

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663550/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-auto-merge-option-in-visual-studio-team-system-200)