# TFS replace trunk with branch

Tags: tfs, version-control, merge, tfvc

I've got a branch from trunk in TFS on which development is complete. I understand that merging back into trunk should be the next step, but due to a situation beyond my control, I am not able to do that. I'm satisfied the branch represents my complete application. Is there a merge option that will simply take the branch as the trunk?

As I read the [MS documentation on MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=vs.100).aspx), the baseless merge comes close to what I want. But, I understand that the trunk files would still be part of the result, which I do not want.

Comment: Could you explain a little about the situation outside of your control?

Comment: Not more than the fact that the trunk and branch were created before I arrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch has a name and a purpose. You could of course rename the branch, or change its purpose. You could also label your current branch... Or create a new branch from your current development branch.

Whether that's a good idea, that's something else.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. My hope is that there is a way to get the branch back the trunk. They are both named for their current purpose, e.g. {AppName} for the trunk, and {AppName}-{Feature} for the branch. So, the branch would definitely need to be renamed if there is no other solution.

Comment: I'd sit down with the team and figure out a way to restore the proper usage of each branch, without renaming. A trunk is a trunk, and renames will work, but if you rename `appname-f1` to `appname`, it'll do crazy things with the history, because the history of the old folder is partially carried over depending on how you check in.

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct, renaming opens more cans of worms. There are procedural changes that we need to refine, and his effort is bringing focus to that fact. As I said before, I appreciate you taking the time to weigh in. I'm biting the bullet and doing a TFS Merge with Automerge set to Off ([link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663550/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-auto-merge-option-in-visual-studio-team-system-200) which will allow me to see each change. For my situation, I'll be taking Source changes.