# Revert TFS branch to original

Tags: tfs, branch

I'm using TFS. On my branch I checked in a bunch of changes, that I now want to undo.

I can click on the branch in TFS Source Control, and view history, and get the original branch, but when I check it out to edit... it reverts back to the branch that I boned.

I tried both "View History" then right clicking on orignal "create" branch and then "get this version"

And I also tried right clicking on the branch and "Get Specific Version".

I also tried deleting the local files for this branch.

How do I just get the original version?

(Note: Deleting + Recreating the branch is a huge process so I'd like to stay away from that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert (Roll Back) a checkin in TFS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694644/how-to-revert-roll-back-a-checkin-in-tfs-2010)

Comment: @JohnSaunders one sec trying to find out

Comment: @JohnSaunders its 2008, and that duplicate is for 2010 with power tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version of TFS you're using and on whether you have the TFS power tools installed, you can either find it in the History Panel (under the Rollback item). You can always do it from the commandline using

> > tf.exe rollback

Comment: tf.exe rollback was what I was looking for. Kind of disappoined I can't do it from the GUI w/o power tools.

Comment: You do get the functionality with a newer version of Visual Studio, against an older TFS. It's really the Visual Studio version that governs this.

Comment: So if I download vs2012, even while using tfs 2008, I can do this from the GUI? Neat, thanks!