# Errors found in a file out of solution and project by Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

So we have a teammate who did a bad commit via TFS, committed half of his work, none of his resources, and let's say that this morning nothing compiles. He's on his way to correct the thing.

Now my question is, how can this be?
Let's say we have Solution A with project B which contains View `A1`, `A2` and `A3`. The **folder** ALSO contains `A5` and `A6` which uses this in the project that has not been compiled.

When we build our solution, Visual Studio shows errors related to `A5` and `A6` saying that there are missing references in these views.

The `B.csproj` **does not include these views**. I'm looking for solutions and ideas to solve this mystery while my teammate comes back to fix his problem (he'll also get a blame for this, probably).

Comment: Are your team using project reference in your solution ? Or just using file reference?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid a recurrence of similar situations. Suggest your team could use **[check in policy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies)**.

> Administrators of Team Foundation version control can add check-in
>   policy requirements. These check-in policies require the user to take
>   actions when they conduct a check-in to source control, for example a
>   user can be required to associate a work item with a changeset.

- **Builds** Requires that the last build was successful before a check-in.

If you are using **GIT** as your source control, you could also using **[branch policies](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies)** which help teams protect their important branches.

For now as a solution, you team could choose to roll back the bad check in(commit), detail steps please refer this link: [How to revert (Roll Back) a checkin in TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694644/how-to-revert-roll-back-a-checkin-in-tfs-2010)